# DOMContentLoaded event triggers when iframe attached

Tags: javascript, events, domcontentloaded

I have a weird problem and i was wondering if this is the normal behaviour of this event. I have an "DOMContentLoaded" event. This event triggers as expected when the DOM is ready. But, if an iframe is attached to the DOM then the "DOMContentLoaded" event triggers again. My question is, is this the expected reaction?

```
            // log
            var msgEl = document.getElementById("content-msg");

            // dom ready
            var loadIfDomReady = function (event) {
              console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
              msgEl.innerHTML += "<br/> DOM fully loaded and parsed";
              alert("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
            }
            window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadIfDomReady(event), false);


            function createIframe() {
                  var _iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
              // shotgun approach
                  _iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
                  _iframe.style.position = "absolute";
                  _iframe.style.display = "none";
                  _iframe.style.width = "0";
                  _iframe.style.height = "0";
                  return _iframe;
            }

            // vars
            var url = "https://codepen.io/alexandro218/pen/zYrpryK";

            function appendIframe() {    
              msgEl.innerHTML = "<br/>Append button clicked";
                if(!refreshIframe) {      
                  var refreshIframe = createIframe();
                  document.body.appendChild(refreshIframe);
                  refreshIframe.src = url;    
                  refreshIframe.onload = function (event) {
                     console.log("iframe is loaded");    
                     msgEl.innerHTML += "<br/>iframe is loaded";
                  };  
                  msgEl.innerHTML += "<br/>!iframe src appended";
                } else {
                  refreshIframe.src = url;   
                  msgEl.innerHTML += "<br/>iframe src appended";
                  console.log("iframe src appended");
                }  
            }
```

link to [pen](https://codepen.io/alexandro218/pen/zYrpryK)

Comment: You are calling `loadIfDomReady` yourself (because you added `(event)`), it's not triggering because of the event. It should be `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadIfDomReady, false)`

Comment: That was a typo, the event still gets triggered when attaching the iFrame, Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Here is what happens: it triggers only once in the parent page (and won't trigger ever again). Then, when you load the same page inside an iframe, the event only happens once **inside** the iframe. That's expected behavior, because the iframe has its own context, its own `window`. You can easily see that by alerting `location.search` on DOM Ready, and adding `?i_am_an_iframe` to the iframe url. You will get different alerts. https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/abdqdmo

Comment: Maybe this simple example makes more sense (open your console, I got tired of alerts ) Look at the different "Hello from ..." you will get on page load and when the iframe loads: https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/XWXZXNL

Comment: location.search did the trick. I understand now. It was driving me crazy. Can you post the code as an answer so i can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is only ever triggered once for each page. You are `alert`ing in the parent page. Then, when you add an iframe of that same page, you are `alert`ing in the iframe page.

You can see a difference, for example, if you show the current page's `location.href` in the alert, and add something like `?i_am_an_iframe` to the iframe URL:

https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/abdqdmo

But your situation does not actually need to use `DOMContentLoaded`
to be reproduced:

```
// On page load
console.log('Hello from ' + window.location.href);

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var _iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  _iframe.src = "https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/XWXZXNL?i_am_an_frame";
  // Add the iframe, which will have the same script running inside it,
  // and hence produce another console.log, but with a different location.href
  document.body.appendChild(_iframe);
});
```

https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/XWXZXNL